# What uses do reading label address have?

Tags: c, gcc, label, memory-address, goto

I wonder what can one use the `var = &&label`, i.e.: the reading of the address of a label for? I can only tell that by taking such address and then using it for jump doesn't require any `__label__ mylabel;` at beginning of the block (what's normally required to be able to jump to such label).

Answer (score 3):

Taking the address of a label with `&&` is a gcc extension.  It allows you to use a variable containing a label address as a destination for `goto`.  For example:

```
void *p = &&l0;
if (x==1) {
    p = &&l1;
} else if (x==2) {
    p = &&l2;
}
goto *p;

l0:
printf("at l0\n");
l1:
printf("at l1\n");
l2:
printf("at l2\n");
```

You can read more details of this feature in the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).